# CSS styling, header and footer resolution dependent

Tags: css, html, wrapper, text-size

CSS style

[image]

is it possible to do the header and the footer contents can be depend on the resolution of a screen??

I plan for the home to be 100% size of the screen but I don't know if the contents can be resized if they resolution is big or small from the default ,especially `divs` and texts.. what would be the best css code that could make out the same effect, that will also be IE friendly.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to do the header and the footer contents can be depend on the resolution of a screen??

--Yes, use media queries in css to hide and show divs with separate content at different screen sizes

```
.header2 {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .header1 {
    display: none;
  }
  .header2 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```